# Accuracy of pets

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I've seen many sources for the accuracy requirements for the Coils of Bahamut, and they're extremely important because missing attacks is crippling - at best it's damage/time lost, at worst you're a tank that can't get aggro.

I play a Summoner, and many guides list pets as falling into the "Flank" category for accuracy, but others just list "Flank + Garuda" - I've also noticed that many (90% or more) Summoners act like Garuda is the only pet that exists.

I prefer Ifrit personally. Contagion ability is useful, but Ifrit's auto-attacks in addition to weaponskills boost my dps by a good 20-25% so... yeah, Ifrit for me.

And this has me wondering, which Accuracy cap does Ifrit (and by extension Titan) use? As a melee pet, does it use accuracy caps based on its position like melee dps classes do? Should I learn to be more aware of my pet's positioning (other than the obvious "not in front of it")? Could I get away with fewer points invested in Accuracy if I position Ifrit behind the target?

Basically, any Ifrit-specific information regarding use in Coils would be handy :D Garuda is not the only pet!

<sub>PS: Scholars, pets need Stoneskin too!</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All summon-pets share the same accuracy (when they attack on flanks), also you should have your acc capped (based on where you are in the game) at all times, you shouldnt be worrying about your pets or you missing attacks.If your summoner has the needed ACC, your pets shouldnt be missing.

It all depends on the fight, for single target Ifrit will be better since he focuses on one target only. Garuda will be better for multiple targets because she has contagion, and that will boost your dps if used correctly.

If you are measuring your dps with a dummy of course ifrit will be higher.

Note that most fights have multiple adds at multiple times, this is why everyone will go for garuda.

The best summoners I have seen in coil rotate their summons (irfrit-garuda) during the fight and use arouse eveytime they have it.
Ex:
turn 5:

- fight starts with adds, use garuda
- adds die switch to ifrit
- snakes will spawn switch to garuda again
- stay with garuda for twister phase with adds
- last phase switch to ifrit again (or sometimes titan to soak damage)

You should always be aware of your pets positioning, and remember to micromanage it as much as possible.

Comment: Your T5 rotation sounds familiar, that's almost exactly what I did XD Thanks for the info, it's helpful ^_^

Comment: just remember that if you are missing attacks, even if you have a perfect rotation / micro management your dps will drop drastically.